# GLFW magenta color causes unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glfw

When I create a window with GLFW (on a Windows operating system) and set `GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER` to `1` via `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, 1);` I can't draw a rect with a magenta color `glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 1.f);`. This color causes the rect to be transparent and makes me able to click through this part of the window.

I did not expect this behavior and also did not find any documentation that explains this.

I used the example code on the [GLFW homepage](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) and added a gray, yellow and magenta rect of which only the gray and yellow rect produce expected behavior.

[Screenshot that shows the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDILP.png)

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    // ADDED THIS LINE
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER, 1);

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // ADDED THE FOLLOWING LINES
        // background
        glColor3f(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f); // gray
        glRectf(-0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f, -0.75f);

        // unexpected behavior: makes part of the window transparent and click through
        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 1.f); // magenta
        glRectf(-0.1f, -0.1f, 0, 0);

        // draws yellow rect
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.f, 0.f); // yellow
        glRectf(-0.1f, 0.1f, 0, 0);


        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

The magenta color gets drawn correctly when `GLFW_TRANSPARENT_FRAMEBUFFER` is set to `0`.

Comment: Which windows version are you using? Depending on your OS, glfw might only support transparency trough a transparency key color.

Comment: also which glfw version, I think older versions used `LWA_COLORKEY`, and newer versions use `LWA_ALPHA`

Comment: @BDL I'm using Windows 10 Pro version 20H2.

Comment: @PeterT I'm using the newest glfw version 3.3.3

Comment: @BDL Thank you for your comments. I have been able to change this color key by calling this function `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(GetActiveWindow(), 0x000000FF, NULL, LWA_COLORKEY);`
`0x000000FF` equals red.

Comment: I could only mention one person in a comment. I would also like to thank you @PeterT

Comment: glfwGetWin32Window is a better function to get the glfw window handle and should be used instead of GetActiveWindow, which could also get the wrong window handle I guess. Posted an extra comment because I can't edit my old comment anymore.

Comment: @dareun: You might want to write a self-answer to your question since this might be a problem more people are interested in.

Comment: I have just found out that my code uses GLFW 3.3.2 and not 3.3.3 as I stated earlier.
There seems to be a change between these versions that results in different behavior. In version 3.3.3 the color magenta gets drawn and `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` seems to have no effect.

Comment: Update: `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` has no effect because the window in version 3.3.3 doesn't seem to have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style by default.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is that the current transparency color key equals magenta. All pixels drawn in this color will be transparent.

In order to change the color key (on a Windows operating system) you can call the function `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`.

This example will change the color key to red:
`SetLayeredWindowAttributes(glfwGetWin32Window(window), RGB(255, 0, 0), NULL, LWA_COLORKEY);`

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) of the function states the following about the color key:

> crKey
>
> Type: COLORREF
>
> A COLORREF structure that specifies the transparency color key to be
> used when composing the layered window. All pixels painted by the
> window in this color will be transparent. To generate a COLORREF, use
> the RGB macro.

In order to call `glfwGetWin32Window` you need to define the macro `#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32` and include `#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>` as explained [here](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__native.html).

Comment: This works fine on GLFW version 3.3.2, but not on version 3.3.3. The initial problem however doesn't occur on version 3.3.3 anymore.

Comment: I guess this commit shows the reason for the initial problem and why it doesn't occur in version 3.3.3 anymore: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/commit/05dd2fa2986c37e7aee3cba917b1d02a3a189390#diff-475ae98b1c5241adc1365b9672ee3c565946a3618c8d6f2e409500eb9dba0395L393-L414